# WordPress website only loading some CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I voluntarily maintain the following website and we have a really strange problem which I cant figure out a solution too. The CSS file seems to only partly load, yet there's no obvious problems in the CSS and it was all working fine a few days ago.

The website is here and its pretty obvious what's wrong: http://meditateincopenhagen.org/

I've tried partially restoring backups, clearing cache etc, disabling and re enabling all plugins. validating the CSS so far I've not managed to find the problem or a solution.

Comment: are you sure there are not any typos in css or any errors in website, analyzing btw. because [previous one](https://web.archive.org/web/20170610133210/http://meditateincopenhagen.org/) looks fine to me

Comment: This is off-topic, unfortunately. Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please also read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I knew It was off topic at the first place, but instead of flagging it I answered because of the urgency. Thanks for adding this info.

Comment: @halfer I understand and thanks for the feedback. I will keep it in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you commented this line as well:

```
@import url("../Nimble/style.css");
```

so the css is not loading, just one silly mistake ;)

Close comments before importing the styles,

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Nimble Child Theme
 Theme URI:      -
 Description:    Nimble Child Theme
 Author:         David Hirst
 Author URI:     -
 Template:       Nimble
 Version:        1.0.0
 */

@import url("../Nimble/style.css");
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to be the error. I have no idea how the import got commented out though as I havnt touched the CSS in days :/. Thank you very much for spotting that :).